# How to get more precise seconds in d3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, timestamp

I have some time data in database as unix timestamp, i.e, 1446151150000. I want to parse it to be hr:min:sec format for d3. So i do it like this:

```
// d.localtime is unix timestamp
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.localtime = parseDate(new Date(Number(d.localtime)).toString().substring(16, 24));
});
```

However I find timestamp `1446151150000` and `1446151150500` have exactly the same converted string `14:39:10`. Namely, `new Date(Number(1446151150000)` and `new Date(Number(1446151150500)` are exactly the same as `Thu Oct 29 2015 14:39:10 GMT-0600 (MDT)`
 although the actual time has 0.5 second difference.

Question, How can I get more precise second? i.e, how to make the converted strings of `1446151150000` and `1446151150500` to be `14:39:10.00` and `14:39:10.50` seperately instead of `14:39:10`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precision is still there, you are just seeing your default locale string representation of the date.  With d3, you can tweak the string formatting using a custom time [format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format).  The specific one you are looking for is:

```
> dtFormat = d3.time.format("%a %b %e %Y %H:%M:%S.%L GMT%Z");
> dtFormat(new Date(1446151150500));
"Thu Oct 29 2015 16:39:10.500 GMT-0400"
```